# Is there a methodology to download and load a R package without installing it?

Tags: software-installation, r

I need to produce some graphics using R package gridExtra, however, I don't have permissions to install packages in the computer I am working on. I tried the methodology explained [Installing packages without root access](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/), but got the next message:

```
Warning in install.packages("gridExtra", lib = "/data/Rpackages/") :
    'lib = "/data/Rpackages/"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("gridExtra", lib = "/data/Rpackages/") : 
    unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

Is there a different methodology to download a R package without root access?

NOTE: I have to mention that I'm not working in the computer itself but using my /scratch/username/ in an HPCC. The cleaner the process the better, I have lots of restrictions regarding installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `lib` parameter; that should install the package in a directory within your home directory:

```
install.packages("gridExtra")
```

If you need to specify a mirror (which appears to be the case), add it using the `repos` parameter; for example:

```
install.packages("gridExtra", repos = "http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr")
```

You can pick an appropriate mirror by running

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

at an `R` prompt somewhere you can run it interactively, then you can determine the mirror's URL by running

```
options("repos")
```

Or you can view the list of mirrors on http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html